# In Ruby, is there a short syntax for testing hash subkeys without throwing an Exception?

Tags: ruby

In PHP I can use the 'at' sign to suppress errors:

```
$count = @$employees['microsoft']['europe']['london'];
```

And if any of those keys don't exist, `$count` will be `NULL`.

Is there such a short syntax in Ruby? The only way I can think of is using `begin` / `end`:

```
begin count = employees[:microsoft][:europe][:london] end
```

Comment: That PHP can be made oblivious to errors in this fashion is a bug, not a feature, because this is abused all the time.

Comment: You might want to rethink your code if you're spending all your time slinging around big nested Hashes like that. Custom classes might make more sense, using arrays as keys might make sense, ...

Comment: @tadman the fact that it is abused in no way makes it a bug. If you know what you're doing it can be an awesome feature.

Comment: @muistooshort I'm not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little clunky but you can do things like:

```
count = employees.try(:[], :microsoft).try(:[],:europe).try(:[],:london)
```

If you're doing this frequently, adding a little patch to the Hash class helps:

```
class Hash
  def dig(*path)
    path.inject(self) do |location, key|
      location.respond_to?(:keys) ? location[key] : nil
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can do it this way:

```
count = employees.dig(:microsoft, :europe, :london)
```

Comment: note that `try` depends on the ActiveSupport gem if you're not using Rails.

Comment: The patch idea is great!

Answer (score 4):

If you use the [andand](https://github.com/raganwald/andand) gem, you can do something like this:

```
employees = {}
employees.andand[:microsoft].andand[:europe].andand[:london] # => nil

employees = { microsoft: { europe: { london: 3 } } }
employees.andand[:microsoft].andand[:europe].andand[:london] # => 3
```

If you don't want to use a gem, you can use [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) with a default value.

```
employees = {}
employees.fetch(:microsoft, {}).fetch(:europe, {}).fetch(:london, nil) # => nil

employees = { microsoft: { europe: { london: 3 } } }
employees.fetch(:microsoft, {}).fetch(:europe, {}).fetch(:london, nil) # => 3
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to do this correctly in pure ruby via fetch.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `rescue` at the end of one-liners instead of having to use a `begin / end` block.
In your case, you might use something like

```
count = employees[:microsoft][:europe][:london] rescue nil
```

which will set `count` to `nil` if one of the subkeys does not exist.

**Edit**

As the comments say, this is not the perfect way of handling most situations, as all thrown exceptions are caught by the `rescue` and important information about other errors may be lost. It should therefore only be used if it doesn't matter what kind of exception is thrown.

Comment: A trailing `rescue` can have bad side effects. If `employees` isn't initialized at all, perhaps because it was misspelled or was out of scope, rescuing and returning nil won't mean what it's assumed to mean, and Ruby won't raise an error signifying the problem. That results in a very hard to diagnose error.

Comment: I'm with the Tin Man here. **Pokemon exception handling** ("Gotta catch'm all") is a really dangerous anti-pattern.

Comment: Just to clarify: I know that this is risky and personally don't like not knowing which exception actually was thrown, but I thought this was what op asked for - should have mentioned this in my answer though.